# Parallelizing multiplication of vectors-like computation in python

Tags: python, multithreading, vector

I have got a chunk of code like

```
for i in range(0, len(a))
    b[i] = func(a[i])
```

where a and b are arrays of the same length, a is given (and big), func is some function that has a lot of local variables but does not use any global variables.

I would like to distribute computations of func across several CPUs. Presumably I need to use multiprocessing module, but I have not found any relevant examples. Could you help? Thanks.

Comment: Which Python interpreter you are using? Note that if using CPython, you need to be aware of GIL: http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: @jsalonen: That's why he needs the multiprocessing module.

Comment: If you are using linux, you can use fork. http://ikharn.blogspot.in/2012/04/multiprocessing-in-python.html

Comment: @Nikhil: Using `fork` is problematic because it doesn't have an easy way of getting results back to the parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the very first code example in the [`multiprocessing` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# you could define `func`, `a` here

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = Pool() # use all available CPU cores
    b = p.map(func, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use process pool. You can see a full sample in my github: https://github.com/mariazverina/codejam/blob/master/src/main.py

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(4)  # set to number of cores
b = p.map(func, a)
```

Comment: good point - brain -> fingers malfunction - updated explanation above

Comment: on Windows `if __name__=="__main__"` is mandatory when using `multiprocessing`.